# Logging numeric values as intermediate output in python script

Tags: python, debugging, logging, numeric

I have a function which computes some mathematical function. In debugging I would like to

## mylib.py

```
def function(a, b, c):
    """
    compute a numerical function of a, b, c 
    using complex math functions g, h
    """
    d = g(a)
    e = h(b, c)

    return d*sin(e)
```

In main this function gets called multiple times

## main.py

```
for a in range(0, 50):
   print d*e
```

The function does not return what I expected and I would like to see how the intermediate variables d, e vary for the different parameters.

I have added simple print statements (print d, print e) to function, but this is not convenient as I would like to plot d and e for each value of a. Is there a way to write d and e to a file, so that after I run main.py  I can easily load the output and make a plot?

I also tried

```
def function(a, b, c):
    """
    compute a numerical function of a, b, c 
    using complex math functions g, h
    """
    d = g(a)
    e = h(b, c)
    logging.debug(str(d)+','+str(e))

    return d*sin(e)
```

and

```
logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
for a in range(0.0, 50.0):
   print d*e
```

but I can't find the log file anywhere.

Cheers, Mike

Comment: the log file should be in the same directory you are running the python command

Comment: that's what I would expect, but nothing there.